# Salvation Army and the brass band

Tags: protestantism, tradition, religious-practice, salvation-army

I think it is a tradition to have a [Brass Band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brass_band) in almost every church in the Salvation Army. I see them performing on many occasions like Easter Sunday and Christmas. Here is a sample image ([source](http://www.salvationarmy.org.uk/uki/Brass_Bands_Heathrow_Airport)):

[image: Salvation Army Brass Band]

Another image ([source](http://neoevsmith.blogspot.in/2011/01/1-1-11.html)): [image]

What is the importance of Brass Band in the Salvation Army?

Is it compulsory for a Salvation Army church to have a brass band?

Comment: It's probably to keep within the military theme of their denomination. The military uses brass bands, so they do too: http://www.goarmy.com/band/types-of-army-bands.html I won't put this as an actual answer because I don't know.

Comment: Steve is probably spot on in his observation.  Army, band, brass band are terms that seem to go together.  Also, a brass band can attract attention and draw people to the Salvation Army Christmas kettles that spring up all over the place in December, at least in America, if not elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **The primary purpose is to serve as an instrument to proclaim The Gospel of Jesus Christ.** All other goals of the band are considered "Proper" when their ultimate goal is observed.
2. The brass band may be seen as **an evangelical tool** to generate a spiritual response by helping to set the mood & enhancing a spiritual message.
3. **Member retention.** Many members were introduced through to the Salvation Army through the brass band, & some may have strayed if not for their attachment to the band.
4. Drawing attention & Publicity **for fundraising**
5. **Christian fellowship** for players

The brass bands also seem to be more popular in the United Kingdom than in the United States.

Here is some more information about the Salvation Army Brass Band :

- [Some history & information](http://www.brassbandinformation.co.uk/salvation-army-brass-bands.html)
- [About the International "Staff" band of the Salvation Army (The top Salvation Army band)](http://www.theisb.com/)
- [A 1932 "Appreciation" flier (Back than, the band was called "Callender's Band")](http://www.satiche.org.uk/vinbbp/phot6776.jpg)
- [The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvation_Army_brass_band)

I hope this little bit of information was helpful.